# Cannot install apt-install in Ubuntu 16.04 "waiting to install "

Tags: 16.04

Today I installed Ubuntu 16.04.
I can install all software in Ubuntu Software.
But when install not in official package. Ubuntu show like:

`This software comes from a 3rd party and may contain non-free components.`

Click button `Install` but don't have anything occurs.

In left launcher bar show icon ? with process bar not run, this process name:
`waiting to install`.

It appear and not complete, I waiting to install `chrome or nylas n1,....` with 45 minutes but not anything happen.

I tried install with terminal. Git-core, mc, vim can install perfect but other software don't work.

Comment: having a similer issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm having the same issue with Ubuntu Software with Ubuntu 16.04, but I found an easy GUI workaround in the meantime via "GDebi Package Installer" so you don't have to fiddle around with CLI with all your .deb packages and it'll capture all the dependencies so you don't have to worry about forcing apt-get installs.

1. run "sudo apt-get install gdebi"
2. In Nautilus, right-click your .deb file and select "Open With" -> "GDebi Package Installer"
3. Select "Install Package" to install.

Info was found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/install-from-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another method to resolved this problem.

From Ubuntu Software Center newer version, search keyword "Ubuntu Software Center" and install it.
> Right-click to .deb file and Open With > Ubuntu Software.